# How make sense of StringToSliceByte in rpcx lib?

Tags: go

The code snippet below is come from [rpcx](https://github.com/smallnest/rpcx/blob/91085a7998e30b14da010179017214a58ea9c59b/util/converter.go) lib.

```
func StringToSliceByte(s string) []byte {
    x := (*[2]uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
    h := [3]uintptr{x[0], x[1], x[1]}
    return *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&h))
}
```

The code is used to convert a string to a byte slice efficiently, but how it works? Can someone provide a thorough analysis of this code?

By the way, there is a more concise implementation as well:

```
func toBytes(s string) []byte {
    return *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
}
```

It seams the code below works as well:

```
func StringToSliceByte(s string) []byte {
    x := (*[1]int8)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
    return *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&x[0]))
}
```

Comment: It's essentially doing an unsafe typecast of the memory of a string to a byte slice. This is prohibited by the Go spec, because it makes for mutable strings. But it can be done as an efficiency shortcut, so long as the internal memory structure doesn't change (which is not guaranteed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string contains a pointer to an underlying array containing the string data, and the string length. A slice contains a pointer to the underlying array, length, and capacity of the slice.

The line:

```
x := (*[2]uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
```

accesses the internal representation of the string `s`.

The assignment:

```
    h := [3]uintptr{x[0], x[1], x[1]}
```

creates a slice `h` pointing to the underlying array of `s` (`x[0]`), with length and capacity equal to the string lenhth `x[1]`.

Then it returns this as a slice.

As you can tell from the use of `unsafe`, this is an unsafe piece of code, and it may not work with later versions of Go. It relies on internal representation of data types. It also violates the fact that strings are immutable in Go by returning the underlying array of the string as a slice. It is an optimization made to prevent copying by sacrificing type safety and language assumptions. Avoid it.

Comment: `why func StringToSliceByte(s string) []byte {
    x := (*[1]int8)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
    return *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&x[0]))
}`  seams works a well?

Comment: @fish: print the length and capacity from each version.

Comment: all versions print length: 5, version1 cap: 5, version2 cap: 4212505, version 3 cap: 4593300  @JimB

Comment: @fish, yes exactly, the other versions are not setting the capacity and are reading random values from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Since go1.20, you could do this safer:

```
func StringToSliceByte(s string) []byte {
    return unsafe.Slice(unsafe.StringData(s), len(s))
}
```

Comment: you are right, i'm just curious about old hack ways.